# Best place to increase a counter field in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have two `Models` in Django:

Book:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    number_of_readers = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Reader:

```
class Reader(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    name_of_reader = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

Everytime I add a new `Reader` to the database I want to increase `number_of_readers` in the `Book` model by 1. I do not want to dynamically count number of rows `Reader` rows, related to a particular `Book`, for performance reasons.

Where would be the best place to increase the `number_of_readers` field? In the `Serializer` or in the `Model`? And what method shall I use? Should I override `.save` in the `Model`? Or something else in the `Serializer`?

Even better if someone could provide a full blown example on how to modify the `Book` table when doing a post of a new `Reader`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it easily and efficiently, if you decide to use raw SQL instead of Django's ORM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't do this on the *REST API level*, I'd do it on the *model level*, because then the +1 increase will always happen, regardless of where it happened (not only when you hit a particular REST view/serializer)

### Django signals

> Everytime I add a new Reader to the database I want to increase number_of_readers in the Book model by 1

I'd implement a `post_save` signal that triggers when a model (Reader) is *created*

There is a parameter to that signal called `created`, that is `True` when the model is created, which makes more convenient than the `Model.save()` override

**Example outline**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def my_callback(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        reader = instance
        book = reader.book
        book.number_of_readers += 1 # prone to race condition, more on that below
        book.save(update_fields='number_of_readers') # save the counter field only

post_save.connect(my_callback, sender=your.models.Reader)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

**Race Conditions**

In the above code snippet, if you'd like to avoid a race condition (can happen when many threads updating the same counter), you can also replace the `book.number_of_readers += 1` part with an F expression `F('number_of_readers') + 1`, which makes the read/write on the DB level instead of Python,

```
book.number_of_readers = F('number_of_readers') + 1
book.save(update_fields='number_of_readers')
```

more on that here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f

<sub>There is a `post_delete` signal too, to reverse the counter, if you ever think of supporting "unreading" a book :)</sub>

### Batch or periodic updates

<sub>If you wish to have batch imports of readers, or need to periodically update (or "reflow") the reader counts (e.g. once a week), you can in addition of the above, implement a function that recounts the readers and update the `Book.number_of_readers`</sub>

Comment: Spot on - this saves you from running around looking for the reason your count doesn't add up.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the design of your app and particularly on where you will reuse this logic.

For example, if you want the same logic for adding `Reader`s everywhere in your app, do it in a signal, as bakkal suggests or in `save`. If it depends on the API endpoint, you might want to do it in a view.

It will also depend if you are doing bulk inserts of readers: if you do it in `save` or a `pre_`/`post_save` it will not work for bulk updates, so it would be better to do it in `QuerySet`'s `create` and `bulk_create` methods etc.

From performance point of view, you might want to use F expressions, no matter where you do it:

```
book.number_of_readers = F('number_of_readers') + added_readers_count
```

Comment: Why did you remove your example with using the F-macro to "remove" a read back from the databae?

Comment: I thought for some reason for a moment that it didn't improve anything =) Actually i was right in the original version.