# How to safely update the balance field in django

Tags: python, django

I need to use a wallet model in my project. If I need to update the balance of the wallet, what is the safest way to do it? For example, if different threads or different processes increase the balance of the wallet at the same time, will there be any problems?

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    balance = models.DecimalField(_('Balance'), max_digits=18, decimal_places=8, default=0)

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount

    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.balance = self.balance + amount
```

Is this model above safe? If not, what is the best practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best place to increase a counter field in Django REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667007/best-place-to-increase-a-counter-field-in-django-rest)

Comment: see "race conditions" block

Comment: If you are using RDS (MySQL, PostgreSQL) as your database,  insertions/updates are atomic in nature. So, race conditions are handled by default.